# Can't set correct permissions on share mapping

Tags: linux, samba

Im trying to setup a samba share. I want the share to have access rights rwxrwsrws so that everyone can red and write to it.

The folder shared on the server where the share resides is sat by `chmod 777` to `rwxrwsrws`.

The folder on the client computer has also been sat by `chmod 777` to `rwxrwsrws`, but as soon as I map that folder to the share the permissions are changed to `rwxr x r x` when I view it by ls -l and I can't write to the maped folder by using a user that's different from the owner.

**Here's what I have done so far:**

1. Installed samba on a server
2. Sat 777 on the folder /data by chmod 777 and shared it by samba
3. On the client computer sat 777 on a folder /data (by `chmod 777`)
4. Mapped this folder to the share on the server

**This is how I have configured the samba share:**

```
[global]

security = user

unix extensions = no

map to guest = Bad User

public = yes

guest account = nobody


[public]

path = /disk2/data

guest ok = yes

writable = yes

browsable = yes

public = yes

directory mask = 0777

directory security mask = 0777

force directory mode = 0777

force directory security mode = 0777

hide dot files = no
```

**This is how I have mapped the folder to the share on the client computer:**

```
Sudo mount –t cifs //xx.xx.xx.xx/public /data –o user=nobody
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory that you have created and shared via SAMBA in the server is `rwxrwsrws`  and the directory you have created in Client is `rwxrwsrws`.

But once you have mounted the share via `sudo`, that directory will become `rwxr x r x`

So ultimately you need to mount the samba share and then change the directory permission.

```
# chmod -R 777 /data/
```

Never mount network files as Root user.

```
mount –t cifs //xx.xx.xx.xx/public /data –o user=nobody
```

For permanent mount and auto permission change.

Add this in `/etc/fstab`

```
//xx.xx.xx.xx/public /data cifs username=nobody,network,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noperm
```

Note: Also keep in mind that cifs is supposed to be for user mounts not entire systems. It basically assumes you will be mounting 1 user on this side to 1 user on that side

Comment: Thanks Ruban, 

You solved my problem :)

I had alredy tried to use chmod 777 after I had maped the folder to the share but it still could not change from rwx r x r x, also the chown -R root:root /data didn't change anything.

What worked however was you line in /etc/fstab

The one I had put in there myself and didn't Work was:
//10.4.98.110/public /data cifs user=nobody 0 0